# FOP remove the distances between inline-containers

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am tasked with using FOP to print price tags. It is necessary that as much as possible price tags fit on one sheet. For this I represent the price tags as a block-container and put them on a sheet through an inline-container. There were several questions about how to remove the distances between inline-containers and there is for some other way in FOP to implement my task other than tables.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
      <fo:region-body/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

      <fo:block>

      <fo:inline-container width="65mm" height="40mm"  >
        <fo:block-container width="65mm" height="40mm" border="solid black 1pt" overflow="hidden">
        <fo:block>
        <fo:inline-container width="49%" text-align="right" >
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        </fo:inline-container>
        <fo:inline-container width="49%" >
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        </fo:inline-container>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>

      </fo:inline-container>

      <fo:inline-container width="65mm" height="40mm"  >
        <fo:block-container width="65mm" height="40mm" border="solid black 1pt" overflow="hidden">
        <fo:block>
        <fo:inline-container width="49%" text-align="right" >
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        </fo:inline-container>
        <fo:inline-container width="49%" >
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>

        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        <fo:block>test</fo:block>
        </fo:inline-container>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>

      </fo:inline-container>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using tables?  What distance between inline containers are you talking about?  Is it horizontal or vertical distance?  Can you add a screenshot of your current result where the extra distance appears?

Comment: @Tony Graham Thank you for participating in my problem <fo:inline-container width="64mm" height="39mm"  >
        <fo:block-container width="65mm" height="40mm"> solved it